# How can I minify CSS? Shorthand for property [ background-position ]?

Tags: css, background, minify, background-position

Mix 1 look at the source-code of my site with 19 chars of byte-wasting letters `background-position`, for the sprite icons positions, and you get a feel of my little frustration on this long word:

**`background-position`**

Using it singularly is fine, but when setting hundreds of sprite icons it's just silly byte-wasting. So my question is: **is there any smarter shorthand** that can replace this long word? If so, it would save me half my page's bytes!

Just have a look at the insanity of it on the pic below...

Cheers and much appreciated!

## update:

notice that every single icon has its own, unique icon and unique background offset.

---

[image]

Comment: Don't use inline CSS? :D

Comment: Just nitpicking here, `background-position` is a property, not a selector :)

Comment: @Alex thanks! corrected in title.

Comment: @Myles Gray, sorry thats just unusefull comment. Think for a minute about it: whether the unique offset positions appear in html or in css, that does not matter for total bytes. IN FACT, your suggestion would make things much much larger, because now, in addition to the property `background-position`= -xxx; i have to define classes, and make inline `class="icon109"` for every icon and `.icon109{ background-position = -XXX}`  not to mention the overall added overhead of having to define every icon needlessly into each own class.... Sorry but those three upvotes on your comment are strange!

Comment: Repeating "background-position" over and over again gzips really well. You could probably save a lot more bytes by ensuring that you have gzip compression enabled.

Comment: @Sam: Even if you have to create unique classes for each icon, your `.css` file will be cached.. and the page will not. Add in `gzip encoding` as suggested by @Annie, and you're saving yourself quite a good chunk of bandwidth.

Comment: @Annie, AWESOME tip which answers my question really! Just checked and my little HTTP supports compression. Saving 73% of its original size `from 31,874 >> 8,484 bytes`... bautifull. creative solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**An** approach would be to encode the background-position in a class name and then use javascript to convert this into element styling.

So

```
 <p class="mnu" style="background-position: 0 -1690px">
```

becomes

```
 <p class="mnu bg p$0$-1690">
```

Then you do something like

```
$('.bg').each( function() {
  var elem = $(this);
  var classes = elem.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  $.each(classes, function(index, classname) {
    if(classname.indexOf('p$') != -1) {
      var coords = new Array();
      coords = classname.split('$');

      elem.css('background-position', coords[1]+"px "+coords[2]+"px");
    }
  });
});
```

In effective, you've got your own de-minifier there. I'm not saying it's the best way to do it, but it does address your concern of HTML file size (at the expense of rendering time).

Comment: Just thought of a variation on this: instead of encoding the position in the class name, you could create a dictionary of positions, by creating an associative array on the fly that is fed to the de-minifier. The element classes then refer to an entry in the position dictionary. Not sure if that improves performance or size, but it's an alternative and I like TMTOWTDI

Answer (score 1):

Using simply `background` seems to [overwrite the actual background image](http://jsfiddle.net/esvRZ/), so looks like `background-position` is your only bet.

Still, you could use classes instead, example...

#### HTML

```
<div class="sprite-button save">Save</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.sprite-button {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background-image: url(sprites.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   text-indent: -9999px;
}

.save {
   background-position: -30px 0; 
}
```

Still, unless you are Google, Facebook, etc, saving this many bytes probably isn't worth the trouble (beyond my example above).

Comment: Yes, CSS files and selectors are the way to go. However, from the look of Sam's markup, **every** `<li>` has a different background image so he is doomed to eat bytes ;)

Comment: @Nimrod Yeah, if he used the individual sprites a few times, the classes would save bytes. Still, in an external stylesheet with the right expiry headers, it will be downloaded once. Inline styles will be downloaded per different page view.

Comment: @alex, I meant the bytes from all the repeated `background-position:` text that Sam was complaining about, not the image itself.

Comment: @Nimrod That's what I was talking about :P

Comment: @Nimrod, I think you are right, and `I am doomed to eat bytes...` oh well as long as this eating disorders remains in the digital realm...